# Private version control without server

Tags: controls, version

My network configuration doesn't allow the computer to run as a server, so Subversion and others are out. Github offers non-public version controlling only for paying customers.

Anybody knows a solution where a few developers can work on the same code, for free, without sharing it with the whole world. Even merging directories between pendrives would do, if such software exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/plans) does private repositories for up to 5 developers. BitBucket does Git or Mercurial, take your pick.

Comment: not really the right answer. What OP is looking for is a free, server-less CVS, and git can do that. OP and you are confusing git and github.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're confusing [Git](http://git-scm.com/) with [GitHub](http://www.github.com).

Git can do all you want, for free.

Comment: GitHub charges for private repositories.

Comment: So...? Like I said, Git can do all he wants, for free. I did not say GitHub could. Indeed, I pointed out he's confusing Git (the software) with GitHub (a platform/service/website). To quote: "Git offers non-public [...]".

Comment: But you need a server for Git, don't you?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. You could even implement the 'transport repositories via flash drives' idea. A Git repository is just a regular directory with files in it. If you have that, you can work with it.