# Create an offline version control for R Studio

Tags: git, version-control, rstudio

I need to create a (private) version control where I would be the only one to have access in it. I would like some opinions about how would be possible to have the repository in your local drive instead of an online one.

In these other questions [private-version-control-without-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208072/private-version-control-without-server) and [collaborate-using-git-without-remote-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559590/collaborate-using-git-without-remote-server) it seems to be possible using Git, but no one provides actual insights. Any helps?

Comment: Just `git init` and you're good to go. What specific issues do you need "actual insights" on?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have downloaded Git for Windows from http://msysgit.github.com/ . It installed correctly but when I tried to actually create a project in R-Studio with a version control (giving the path of a directory in place of the URL of the repository) I got:

fatal: '.....\R-project\Repository' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Probably I am doing it conceptually wrong. What di you actual suggest? Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with R Studio but the error message indicates you are attempting to clone something whereas you just want to create a new local repository with `git init`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Version control without remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547109/version-control-without-remote-repository)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. it was me trying to make the same question BUT I got 'closed'.... anyway I solved as you can read below. But you got the point that was the problem. thanks for replying.

Comment: "It is not a duplicate." "it was me trying to make the same question" These two statements are inconsistent. If it's the same question you should either update the original question or delete the original and start from fresh. Having both visible just uses up people's time unnecessarily.

Comment: They are not! I wasn't making the same question of someone else. If you all had not been so rude and had answered my question immediately without uselessly questioning about the question itself I would never made the same question twice...

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought I was being rude, I cannot comment on behalf of anyone else. A question can be duplicate of another question even if it wasn't asked by a different user, I'm not sure why you'd think otherwise.

Comment: I don't, I just re-made the question because the other was closed and I couldn't spend too much working time in learning how to re-open the question. I am off now :-) and having a look at the faq to remove the post as you said. Anyway I didn't mean you before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git works quite fine even if you have only one repository. The usual workflow is that you always work on your own, local repository. You can shared changes with other ("remote") repositories, but you don't have to. The local repository can do everything on its own, including branching and browsing history.

Comment: Thank you, I just solved. I didn't know I had to use the Git GUI to create a repository in the targeted folder before creating the project with RStudio. I thought it was an automatic step. thanks again